# R:Trying to understand the logic in order to replace loops with lapply()

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply, lapply

I am a beginner in R and I would like to be more familiar with the apply() functions since the loops are in general avoided in R to the best of my knowledge.

There are some double or triple loops (loop within a loop within a loop) that is difficult for me to "replace" them with lapply() function.

So, for instance I have the following code:

```
im <- 1
ig <- 1
for(im in 1:nrow(dataframe1)){
  for(ig in 1:nrow(dataframe2)){
    if(grepl(dataframe2$name[ig], dataframe1$Text[im])){
      dataframe1$reference[im] <- dataframe1$reference[im] + 1
      cat("match found between:", im, "and ig:", ig)
      ig <- ig + 1
    }else{
      cat("no word match found between im:", im, "and ig:", ig)
      ig <- ig + 1
    }}
  im <- im + 1
  ig <- 1
}
```

How could I replace the two loops with the lapply() (or apply(), or sapply()) function in R?
Hoping to get into the apply() logic after that.

Comment: Could you post small reproducible example with expected output? Your code seems a bit odd (for instance, you update `ig <- ig + 1` but it's your indexing var in `for (ig in ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to rewrite your loops (corrected) with `*apply` functions and I believe that in this case you are better off with good old `for` loops.

With made up datasets, here is your code but right.

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame(Text = c("Ronald Fisher", "Karl Pearson", "William Gosset",
                                  "Harald Cramer", "Andrey Kolmogorov"),
                          reference = 11:15, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dataframe2 <- data.frame(name = c("Ronald", "Harald"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(im in 1:nrow(dataframe1)){
  for(ig in 1:nrow(dataframe2)){
    if(grepl(dataframe2$name[ig], dataframe1$Text[im])){
      dataframe1$reference[im] <- dataframe1$reference[im] + 1
      cat("match found between:", im, "and ig:", ig, "\n")
    }else{
      cat("no word match found between im:", im, "and ig:", ig, "\n")
    }
  }
}

dataframe1
#               Text reference
#1     Ronald Fisher        12
#2      Karl Pearson        12
#3    William Gosset        13
#4     Harald Cramer        15
#5 Andrey Kolmogorov        15
```

Comment: Actually my code (the one i published) is working correctly. This is not my problem. My problem is how could I replace the loops (the for functions) with the lapply functions.

Comment: Sorry Rui, where are in the code you wrote are the apply functions?